# a table of strings: to add an int key, or not to add?

Tags: c#, database, code-first

In reference to answer 1 of the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8201716/ef-code-first-not-generating-table-for-icollectionstring), the answer states that 
it is better to have a table with an ID (primary key) field and a string field, rather than just a string field that is also the primary key.

In short, I need to store a table of unique strings (each string should appear only once in the table). I don't know enough about DB implementation, so I would appreciate some education explanation about which method is best (in my case).

Thanks,

Comment: So this table just has one column in it, the string?  Or are there other columns as well, and if so, would you have any other indexes on the table?

Comment: The table contains only the string field (a limitation imposed by the entity framework - I encountered the exact problem described in the referenced question)

Comment: Makes sense, I'd agree with Internet Engineer then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need an ID field if you make the string field as the primary key.

In regards to performance Integers will always outperform strings. But in your case it does not matter.

Note: Making the string field the primary key will ensure all values are unique.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to have an int ID field if your primary key otherwise would have to be 2+ fields (especially if you have a reference to this table in other tables).

Answer (score 0):

I would add an int/long ID. It makes references faster and cleaner. The handling is easier too, especially if you have very long strings (e.g sentence).