# Comma-separated foreign keys using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, foreign-keys

I'm using code-first approach in Entity Framework.

I'm using two classes: `Item` and `Tag`. An `Item` can have multiple `Tag`s

```
public class Item
{
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}

public class Tag    
{
    public int TagId { get; set; }
    public int Name { get; set; }
    public Item Item { get; set; }
}
```

I want to place the `TagId`'s in `Items` table as comma-separated values.

Can I use a foreign key association to achieve this? If so how can I retrieve data while using it? Or please specify an alternative method.

Comment: check [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8201716/ef-code-first-not-generating-table-for-icollectionstring) if it helps

Comment: Please, PLEASE, ***PLEASE*** don't do that!! Gosh, when are programmers going to stop this madness..... you have a nice FK relationship - `Tag` has a connection to the `Item` - just use that! Don't mangle that proper FK relationship into a comma-separated string - which you'll have to "unmangle" again next time you want to join...... please, seriously: **DON'T DO THIS!**

Comment: @marc_s Can you please explain?

Comment: You need to explain - **why on earth** do you want to mangle all your FK values into a comma-separated string? Each `Tag` in the database will have an `ItemID` column that links it to the `Item.ItemID` value via a **proper** foreign key relation; each `Tag` in the .NET runtime has an associated `Item` that it belongs to; each `Item` has a list of `Tag`s that are associated with it - what do you need another comma-separated column for? What's the point??

Comment: I have about 5000 Items and each Item has about 3-6 tags each so you are saying me to place about 5000 * 6 = 30000 rows in a table to associate and the amount of Items may also increase. Wouldn't that be a memory loss placing all the repetition of tags and wouldn't that be a performance hit if I need to search basing on Tags?

Comment: If you want to store 30'000 tags - you'll have to store 30'000 tags - no way around this. And it's **much better** to store them properly in a relational table, with a **proper** foreign key relationship in place, rather than creating messy comma-separated value strings.... 30'000 rows is ***ABSOLUTELY NOTHING*** for SQL Server - talk about **30 billion rows**, yes, then we'll get into interesting territory ....

Answer (score 1):

You can expose it as a not mapped property, i.e:

```
public class Item
{
  public int ItemId { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public List<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
  [NotMapped]
  public string TagIds
  {
    set
    {
      if (Tags == null) return null;
      return string.Join(",", Tags.Select(t => t.TagId.ToString).ToArray());
    }
    //get
    //{
       // If you need you can implement this with string.Split and update the Tags
    //}
  }
}
```

I don't know if you need to implement the get. If you do, you can use `string.Split()` and `int.Parse()` to get the new tag ids, and update them in the DB.