# Storing IEnumerable<string> in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

Is it possible to store an `IEnumerable<string>` in Entity Framework?

I'm using code-first in ASP.NET MVC5 and I have a model that looks a little like this, but `ImageUris` does not appear as a column in my database (all the other properties do).

```
public class Product
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Condition { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<string> ImageUris { get; set; }
}
```

PS: In case you are interested in why I'm storing Uris rather than images themselves, they are uris to Azure Storage Blobs.

Comment: possible duplicate of [EF Code First not generating table for ICollection<string>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8201716/ef-code-first-not-generating-table-for-icollectionstring)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot save multiple records in single column of the relational database. There is no such data type that supports this.

You can create a separate table for Image Uris and then store your image Uris there.

Your entity code would look something like this:

```
public class Product
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public string Condition { get; set; }

    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ImageUri> ImageUris { get; set; }
}

public class ImageUri
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Uri { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure EF won't automatically create the table to store the strings?

Comment: Nope that will never happen, Entity framework does what your code tells it to do.